# Batch copy gives errors, xcopy works fine

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, xcopy

I am writing a general file backup program.  It searches the drive for files matching a set of types and then writes them to a folder on the desktop.  I wrote it using `xcopy` on Windows XP but upon learning that `xcopy` was deprecated in favor of `robocopy` in Vista and newer, still wanting to maintain compatibility I decided to switch to the non-deprecated `copy`.

This is where the problems begin.  I'm trying to fix the copy routine.  I thought I had everything sorted out, but it doesn't copy anything.  My output is zero files copied for every iteration.

Original Code using `xcopy`:

```
for /r %%a in (*.bmp *.dds *.gif *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.psd *.pspimage *.tga *.thm *.tif *.tiff) do (
   echo f | xcopy "%%a" "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\LDR\Images\Bitmap\%%~nxa" /q /y /g /c
)
```

Revised (broken) Code using `copy`:

```
for /r %%a in (*.bmp *.dds *.gif *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.psd *.pspimage *.tga *.thm *.tif *.tiff) do (
   copy "%%a" "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\LDR\Images\Bitmap\%%~nxa" /d /y /z
)
```

Output:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
    0 files copied.
```

I know that it seems everyone uses either `xcopy` or `robocopy` but can anyone help with `copy`?

Note: I'm using Batch to keep it very lightweight and command-line accessible.

Comment: you might find the problem if you insert the word 'echo' before the word 'copy'.  And it may arguably make things clearer if you stick an @ here `@for` and here `do @(`  that should list all the commands and you may see whatever flaw.  I notice also you are missing double quotes in your copy command. You had them in your xcopy command

Comment: just a suggestion, think it would work a little easier with "forfiles".

e.g : forfiles /p c:\ /s /m *.bmp /c "cmd /c copy @file  "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\LDR\Images\Bitmap\%%~nxa"

more info here --> http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Comment: @barlop Sorry, that was a revision I posted.  The one I thought was totally correct is up now.  I caught my mistake after I posted it.

Comment: @deeviate forfiles isn't native to XP and I want this to be a drop-in solution for XP as well as 8 and 98.  I'm looking for compatibility across the board.

Comment: @ndm13 and with quotes and it still doesn't work? try some troubleshooting.. with echo and try just *.bmp and try a shorter directory to copy to.

Comment: `D:\>(copy "D:\Program Files\Winamp\Plugins\avs\whacko6-07.bmp" "C:\Documents and
 Settings\,,,,\Desktop\LDR\Images\Bitmap\whacko6-07.bmp" /d /y /z
)
The system cannot find the path specified.
        0 file(s) copied.`
A sample on a test drive D.  The results were all the same.

Comment: @deeviate I don't see what the issue could be because it worked fine for `xcopy`.  The same variables were passed, and you can see that it rendered the homepath correctly and found the bitmaps.

Comment: Solution found.  I'll post the answer when StackExchange lets me.  For the record, `copy` does not create filepaths, so it failed to copy to a path that `xcopy` would have created for me.  I'll have to pre-create my directories I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution finally found!

Apparently `xcopy` creates directories if they're not specified.  I didn't have the `\LDR\Images\Bitmap` filepath laid out already.  `copy` doesn't know how to make folders so I'll have to generate them beforehand, which is a little annoying because with `xcopy` it wouldn't make folders when there weren't any files to put in them.  With `copy` I'm making folders assuming they'll be filled.

Thanks for the help.  **FOR THE RECORD: `copy` does not create nonexistent file paths.  `xcopy` does!**

UPDATE: My final solution.  Runs like a champ.

```
for /r %%a in (*.bmp *.dds *.gif *.jpg *.jpeg *.png *.psd *.pspimage *.tga *.thm *.tif *.tiff) do (
   if not exist "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\LDR\Images\Bitmap\" (md "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\LDR\Images\Bitmap\")
   copy "%%a" "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\LDR\Images\Bitmap\%%~nxa" /d /y /z
)
```